# Core Plot label not showing

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I downloaded library coreplot and I tried the example in this tutorial: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application.

I have two problem:

1) When I compiled example i don't have error and warning but label of example not showing.

2) inside the tutorial the command `axisSet.xAxis.axisLabelOffset = 3.0f;` give me a error " error: 'axisSet' undeclared (first use in this function)".

What is the problem? 
is very important for me a speed reply thank you all :)
best regard

Answer (score 1):

That tutorial is very useful for adding Core Plot to an iPhone app, but the example plots are out of date. If you look into the comments, there is some updated the code, but that may even be out of date.

I would recommend looking at the example apps included with the Core Plot framework. Also, I have been able to find some answers by digging through the documentation (after building it).

**EDIT**:

Refer to [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1):